# Check an empty array object in JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have an empty array like this:

```
{"18":[]}
```

but other JSON are like this:

```
{
    "223": [
        {
            "virtuemart_state_id": "1",
            "state_name": "Alabama"
        },
        {
            "virtuemart_state_id": "2",
            "state_name": "Alaska"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was trying to check that like this:

```
jQuery("#paramsstates_chzn .search-field: input").click(function(){
            var country = jQuery("#country").val(),
            chzn,
            url = "http://localhost/data.php?id="+country;

            jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data){
             console.log(data);
             if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data[country])) {
                 chzn = "<li class='active-result'>Empty</li>";
                 jQuery("ul.chzn-results").html(chzn);
                 return;
             }
            $.each(data[country], function(i, rep){
                chzn += "<li class='active-result' id ='paramsstates_chzn_o_"+ i + "' >"+ rep.state_name +"</li>";
            });

        jQuery("ul.chzn-results").html(chzn);
          });

      });
```

Any idea in where I made mistake because it's wasn't updating ul.chzn-results class area.

HTML:

```
<ul class="chzn-results"></ul>
```

I tried like this too for length check. But not working.

```
(data[country].length === 0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'check'?

Comment: missing " for  url = "http://localhost/joomla/data.json; .. correct it

Comment: Use `if(Array.isArray(obj) === true && obj.length === 0)` to check if an object is an array and is empty.

Comment: that's an empty array not logically an empty object, simply check for length.

Comment: I tried like this too : `(data[country].length === 0)` but no luck :(

Comment: @techfoobar: That's the way to go. 1) make sure, it is an array at all and after that 2) check the length.

Comment: @user3850712 go here with your `.json` file contents and make sure it's valid JSON http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: `jQuery("#paramsstates_chzn .search-field: input")` is that really supposed to say `.search-field: input` or did you mean `.search-field input`?

Comment: Sorry I was really stupid :( .. I didn't check the HTML ... Sorry but it's working fine. Thanks you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use : `(data[country]).length ==0` to check if array is empty

```
jQuery("#paramsstates_chzn .search-field: input").click(function(){
                var country = jQuery("#country").val(),
                chzn,
                url = "http://localhost/joomla/data.json";

                jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                 if ((data[country]).length ==0) {
                     chzn = "<li class='active-result'>Empty</li>";
                     jQuery("ul.chzn-results").html(chzn);
                     return;
                 }
                $.each(data[country], function(i, rep){
                    chzn += "<li class='active-result' id ='paramsstates_chzn_o_"+ i + "' >"+ rep.state_name +"</li>";
                });

            jQuery("ul.chzn-results").html(chzn);
              });

          });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't know why this wasn't updating this area <ul class="chzn-results"></ul> :(

Comment: please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/8bmZSolmCMlReir850Bf?p=preview  erything looks fine double check your html code

Comment: in line 17 you can change country beteween 18 i 17 to see result

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery, that is plain JavaScript.

```
var o = {"18":[]};
var isEmpty = o["18"].length === 0;
```

Comment: Did you read the other line of the code ? $.each(data[country], function(i, rep){
                chzn += "<li class='active-result' id ='paramsstates_chzn_o_"+ i + "' >"+ rep.state_name +"</li>";
            }); I don't have all JSON empty. I just want to check the empty one.

Comment: Your question only includes a very small snippet of JSON. Please include the *real* JSON in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data[country])) {
```

to

```
if (data[country].length==0) {
```

Comment: @user3850712 Show us the *real* JSON.

Comment: does it add to ul, if the array is non-empty ?